# How do I log data frames in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am relatively new to spark. However I needed to find out that is there are a way by which we can see which data frame is being accessed at what time. Can this be achieved by native spark logging?

If so, then how do I implement this??

Answer (score 0):

The DAG Visualization and Event Timeline are two very important built-in spark tools available from Spark 1.4 that you can use to see which DF/RDD is used and in what steps. See more details here - [Understanding your Spark application through visualization](http://Understanding%20your%20Spark%20application%20through%20visualization)